# Java web start doesn't launch

Tags: java, netbeans, java-web-start

On my Windows 7 x64 machine, I'm having problems launching my remotely deployed Web Start app (the Web Start app launches correctly on another PC as expected).  In IE or FF, I click on the web start launch link, the JNLP is downloaded, it seems to get executed and nothing happens.  I see javaws.exe processes running.  I don't see a java.exe running.

I don't know if it's related but I also can't get the java console to run.  In the Control Panel Java applet settings, I have have enabled "Show console" and "place Java icon in the system tray".  I don't see the Java icon in the system tray either.

I'm running Java 1.6.0_21 (32 bit).  I'm able to run Netbeans so the it appears as if Java is installed correctly on my machine.  Why isn't web start working?

Answer (score 2):

A firewall on my corporate joined domain was the problem.  It was preventing web start as well as other types of apps from working correctly or even launching.  Opening ports resolved it.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know for sure.  I opened up all ports just to get this working.  After I was done, I removed the firewall rule.

Answer (score 1):

Are you absolutely certain that your Windows browser is binding the JNLP suffix to the javaws executable?

If you download the file, and double click, does it open correctly?  If not, then right click, and investigate what is presented under Open With...

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure the binding is correct because I see the javaws.exe process get started when I click on the jnlp file.  I also right clicked on the jnlp file and indeed it is bound to Java Web Start Launcher.

Comment: Then it is time to run "javaws foobar.jnlp" in a CMD.EXE window and see what happens.  javaws has plenty of flags to help you learn more about what goes wrong.

Comment: No diagnostics or error messages when I ran "javaws -verbose launch.jnlp".  The Win7 busy cursor appears for a few secs and then it turns back into the pointer. 

Any reason why I'm having problems viewing the Java console or why I don't see the Java icon in the system tray.  I wonder if this is all related...?

Comment: The app runs fine as a plain old Java app. When I try to run it as a Web Start app from Netbeans, I see this in the output window:

javaws "C:\temp\dist\launch.jnlp"
jnlp:
sign-jars:
generate-jnlp:
Copying 1 file to C:\temp\dist
Deleting: C:\temp\dist\launch.jnlp_
generate-html-preview:
jar:
jws-run:
Splash: server socket failed: No such file or directory
Java Web Start splash screen process exiting .....


Does that offer any clues?

Comment: If nothing happens, then it is confirmed that javaws is broken on this system.  I would suggest completely removing and reinstalling your Java runtime.

Comment: FWIW I'm having this exact problem launching a 3rd party app that I didn't develop (iSyphony, a PBX control panel app). The jnlp file downloads, it has a Java icon, double clicking it results in a busy cursor for a few seconds and then nothing, no error message, just nothing. This is really lame. I have found that if I run javaws.exe *from an administrative command prompt* then it is able to open and launch the package. So I'm guessing it is some kind of permissions issue on 64-bit machines.

Comment: @TimLong Enable the Java console and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptoms when I switched JNLP specifiction to 6.0. So I simply solved it by going back to 1.5, which I think is default in NetBeans, at least up til 6.7.

```
<jnlp spec="6.0+"...
```